# Updating Adobe Flash Player to Tor Browser

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, firefox

When I update Adobe Flash Player, it only updates the Firefox version and not the Tor Browser. How can I update Tor Browser & Adobe Flash Player?

Comment: Is Flash already present in the TorBrowser? (It shouldn't be.)

Comment: Like Andrew said, Flash can give your real IP address out, and cannot ever be enabled.

Answer (score 4):

Plugins, like Flash, are supposed to be disabled because they can bypass Tor and harm your anonymity. Whenever you install or update Flash this should have no effect on any browser that is not installed and it should not affect the TorBrower, because it even seeks to prevent Flash from loading.

Comment: So there is no "protected" version of Flash ? How do I watch video through Tor ?